# When I run setState with a large object my component gets removed from the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, javascript-objects, react-dnd

I'm building an app that lets you organize emojis via drag and drop. I have a method that runs on drop that sorts a large array of emoji objects. When I run setState and commit the object back into a parent component's state, React removes the parent component from the DOM. It just disappears... There are no errors in the console and using react dev tools i can see that the components state has in fact been updated with the new object. Any help would be much appreciated.

This sorting mechanism sends the updated object to it's parent components via props:

```
  endDrag(props, monitor, dragComponent) {
    if (monitor.didDrop()) {

      let sourceEmoji = dragComponent.props.emoji
      let targetEmoji = monitor.getDropResult().props.emoji

      const updatedCategorizedEmojis = props.categorizedEmojis.map((category)=> {
        return category.emojis.map((emoji, idx)=> {
          if (emoji.id == sourceEmoji.id) {
            emoji['newPosition'] = (targetEmoji['newPosition'] - 0.5)
            return emoji
          } else {
            return emoji
          }
        }).sort((a,b)=> {
          if (a['newPosition'] > b['newPosition']) {
            return 1
          }
          if (a['newPosition'] < b['newPosition']) {
            return -1
          }
        }).map((emoji, idx)=> {
          emoji['newPosition'] = idx
          return emoji
        })
      })

      props.updateSortedEmojis(updatedCategorizedEmojis)

    }
  }
```

The array of objects looks like this:

[image]

That whole thing gets added to the parent's state and when it does the component gets removed without errors.

Any info would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you please set up a JSBin with the complete code, demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Does the component get taken out of DOM completely? We would probably need a little more info on the Houdini component to be able to assist.

Comment: Can you post the updateSortedEmojis function?